# Scrapy - save item and parse new url

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and Python, so even after looking the documentation I'm probably missing something.

My star url have to some football tournaments, every tournament has multiple matches. The first parser get all the tournament and makes a new request for each tournament in order to get the matches.
I'm trying to find a way of save the tournament information before make the request to parse the matches. In my mind would be something like:

```
def parse_matches(self, response):
        for match in response.css('#tup_type_1_mkt_grps .rowOdd'):
            #fetching the tournament properties
            tournament = TournamentItem(name=name, country=country...)
            #save the tournament (I don't know how)
            yield scrapy.Request(match.css('a[href]::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_bets)
```

Anyone can think a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it (I was right, I was missing something important). You can create a pipeline to store the items in the database but at the same time you can keep sending urls to be parsed. I was  confused and I tough that both couldn't live together